# Foxpro 2.6 DOS Password

Tags: foxpro

In my college days, I developed an accounting system in legacy programming language foxpro 2.6 DOS Few years ago. It has been a long time since I used it and now I have forgetten the administrator password.

I googled and found no effective tutorial or link or anything as to how I can get the administrator password for foxpro 2.6. I have tried so many times to remember the password, but no success and also I have lost its project file - I have only the executable file.

Can anyone can help me with a short example? How can I recover my program password?

Thanks !!

#### Update

I have found the file *user.dbf* but the password is encoded, I can't understand these words and that is not my password. Do you have any ideas for converting these words to the original password?

Answer (score 0):

FoxPro (any version) doesn't have any sort of built-in passwords. If you coded an application that has a password, then you coded the password system. If you did that properly using one-way encryption then you won't be able to retrieve the password easily if at all.

You also have an EXE and no source code so I think your first step should be getting hold of Refox or another decompilation tool and seeing if you can reconstruct the source. Then check the source for how the passwords work. If you're really lucky you'll be able to rebuild an EXE with the passwords bypassed.

Also the data itself won't be encrypted, if that's all you're interested in.

Comment: i have found user.dbf file but its encoded password to another words
and i cant understand these words and that not my password.
any idea for converting these words to original password?

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned in a comment that you have the user.dbf table.  If you can edit it (after you've backed it up), clear out the field that contains the encrypted password and then try logging in with no password.